# How to get a handle on template dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a gridView that is using a template. 
How can I get access to "shadowText" within my C# in order to hide and display these layers?

Taken from MainPage.xaml

```
   <GridView x:Name="imagesGrid" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MemeTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemClick="imagesGrid_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="323,165,91,54" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" 
                      VerticalChildrenAlignment="Top" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Center" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
```

Taken from app.xaml

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MemeTemplate">
        <Grid Background="#FF939598" Height="250" Width="250">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageBitmap}"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <StackPanel Name="shadowText" Orientation="Vertical" Background="#CC000000" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock 
                    Name="memeCategory" Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                   Margin="10,3,0,0" Width="120" Height="20" 
               TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why can't you use data template's triggers?

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically hide/show the stackpanel in my template or just change the template all together

Comment: Does that "dynamically hide/show" depends on any conditions?

Comment: Yea. What radio button is selected

Comment: So, write `DataTrigger` for your template, bind trigger's condition to radiobutton selection, and set stack panel's `Visibility` in trigger's setters collection.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll just have to continue to search around for examples and learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Give your grid a name and use `findcontrol`

Check if MemeTemplate has find control using intellisense

Comment: My grid doesn't seem to have this function